# Filter a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog, filtering

I'm developing an application written in Prolog. I get to a point in which I want to filter a list of elements and remove those which do not meet a certain constraints or conditions, keeping the original list order. I thought the best way for doing it would be something like this:

```
filter([],Filtered).
filter([L|List],[F|Filtered]) :-
    /* Conditions are met: bypass the element to the filtered list */
    check_conditions(L),
    filter(List,Filtered).
filter([L|List],Filtered) :-
    /* Conditions are not met: do not include the element in the filtered list */
    filter_aborts(List,Filtered).
```

Before accepting it as a solution to my problem I wanted to give it a try (independently), so I compiled and run my code (SWI-Prolog) and tested a few situations. When I type in the Prolog query using a hard-coded list (or whatever you want to call it) I get what something like this:

```
?- filter([id01,id02,id03,id04,id05,id06],F).
F = [id03, id05, id06|_G1024] .
```

The list is certainly filtered but I get this instance name "`_G1024`" at the end of it. I understand this happens because F is not instantiated, but I don't know what would be the solution. Moreover, if I try to do something different like entering the list as an instantiated variable, what I get is even more strange:

```
?- L=[id02,id03,id04,id05,id06].
L = [id02, id03, id04, id05, id06].

?- filter(L,F).
L = [] ;
L = [id01],
F = [id01|_G347] ;
L = [id01, id01],
F = [id01, id01|_G403] 
... and so on.
```

Aren't Prolog variables supposed to be assign-once variables? Does my program actually change `L` or I am not understanding it correctly? A part from that, since I am new to Prolog, I would appreciate any comment regarding my Prolog -let's say...- "style".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your base recursion should be written

```
filter([],[]).
```

and you have a typo

```
filter([L|List],[L|Filtered]) :-
...
```

instead of (second) L you had the singleton F

Comment: I was just about to comment I found the (silly) error when I read your answer. Thank you very much, that was the mistake! Even though, what explains the second error?

Comment: I think about a typo while writing down the question, because the program, as written, will output a list of *not instanced* variables

Answer (score 8):

You use SWI-Prolog, so you can write a predicate which succeeds or fails according to your conditions, then use **include(Predidate, Lst, Success)** . For axample

```
include(check_conditions,Lst, Success)
```

Comment: you are right (+1) the the presented predicate would be better written with include/3, but I ended up by myself to write a filter/3 because I wanted (for a bit of efficiency) to be able to change accepted elements

Comment: Tanks @joel76! I didn't know about this `include/3` predicate. I will use it here, since it perfectly fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to filter by index of array:

```
filterArrByCubeIndexes([],[],_).
filterArrByCubeIndexes([_],[],SI):- isNotCube(SI).
filterArrByCubeIndexes([A],[A],SI):- isNotCube(SI).
filterArrByCubeIndexes([_|T], L, SI):- isNotCube(SI), R1 is SI+1, filterArrByCubeIndexes(T, L, R1).
filterArrByCubeIndexes([X|T], [X|L], SI):- R1 is SI+1, filterArrByCubeIndexes(T, L, R1).

isNotCube(X) :- X=\=round(X**(1/3))*round(X**(1/3))*round(X**(1/3)).



filterArrByCubeIndexes([1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],Z, 1) will produce Z = [1,8]
```